# Is a coherent ring direct limit of Noetherian rings?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

A commutative ring is *coherent* if every finitely generated ideal is finite presented. Every Noetherian ring is coherent.

1. I know polynomial rings with infinite variables is coherent but not Noetherian. And it is direct limit of Noetherian rings in the category of ring. My question: is the converse true? That is, every coherent ring is a direct limit of Noetherian rings?
2. Is there any relation between coherent rings and coherent sheafs?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Adapt this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1680007/polynomial-ring-in-infinitely-many-variables-over-a-noetherian-ring-is-coherent

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez when you answer my question,than I prove this by using extension and contraction of ideals.I want to know the converse.Thank your link!

Comment: See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1587215/121097).